# Explanation of the continuity with respect to norms

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $||.||: \mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N.$

We proved that $||.||$ is continuous in the metric space $(\mathbb R^{n}, ||.||_{2})$.

Now $S_{||.||_{2}}^{n-1}:=\{x\in\mathbb R^{n}:||x||_{2}=1\}$.

And then our professor asserts that since $\{1\}$ is closed space then $S_{||.||_{2}}^{n-1}$ must also be closed, because of the above continuity $(*)$.

My problem with understanding the last line is that:

We have only proven that $||.||$ is continuous in $(\mathbb R^{n},||.||_{2})$, but surely in order for $(*)$ to be true we first need to prove that $||.||_{2}:\mathbb R^{n}\to\mathbb R$ is continuous on $(R^{n},||.||_{2}$ or $||.||)$. In other words the continuity of $||.||: \mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R$ on $(\mathbb R^{n}, ||.||_{2})$ has nothing to do with $S_{||.||_{2}}^{n-1}$?

What am I missing or misunderstanding here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just as a note: you can use "\cdot" for $\cdot$ and "\Vert" for $\Vert$.

Comment: A related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951371/will-the-closed-unit-ball-left-x-right-le-1-in-bbb-rn-be-a-compac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, and your professor was wrong (or you misinterpreted what they were asserting).  To conclude that $S_{||.||_{2}}^{n-1}$ is closed (with respect to the $\|\cdot\|$ topology), you would instead need to know that $\|\cdot\|_2$ is continuous on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|)$.

It is in fact true that $\|\cdot\|_2$ is continuous and therefore $S_{||.||_{2}}^{n-1}$ is closed, but this does not at all follow from what you have written and a separate argument is needed for it.  This follows from the fact that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, for instance, so the topology given by any two norms is the same.  This means that since $S_{||.||_{2}}^{n-1}$ is closed with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$, it is also closed with respect to $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: When you speak of $(\mathbb R, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$, you do mean any norm, right? So that would also include $(\mathbb R, \Vert \cdot \Vert)_{2}$, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is one possible norm.